# Whitespaces after macros in TikZ coordinate names

Tags: tikz-pgf

In TikZ, I'm sometimes in the need to use macros in coordinate names, usually while using `\foreach`. My problem is that macros in coordinate names eliminate any following spaces.

For example, here is an example of this problem:

```
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\a{a}
        \coordinate (\a 1);
        \node at (a1) {Test}; % works correctly
        \node at (a 1) {Test}; % error: "No shape named `a 1' is known.
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In the example I'm using the macro `\a` in the definition of the coordinate `(\a 1)`. I would expect to get the coordinate `(a 1)`, but the whitespace following the macro is eliminated and I end up with just `(a1)`.

Is there any way to tell TikZ (or LaTeX, I don't really know how the macro expansion works behind the scenes) that I want to keep the space after the macro? I've tried escaping it (`(\a\ 1)`, which doesn't compile), adding more spaces (`(\a  1)`, where any number of spaces still get eliminated) and adding some braces (`({\a} 1)` or `(\a{} 1)`, which both kind of work to prevent the elimination of the whitespace, but just because the braces are included in the coordinate name, producing `({a} 1)` and `(a{} 1)` respectively).

Is there a solution for my problem or do I just need to avoid using spaces after macros?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spaces after control sequences get gobbled by TeX because they're there to end the control sequence.

If you use `{a}` or `a{}` the `{}` are going to be part of the node name. (PGF/TikZ uses `\csname` internally to store a node which just works that way).

`\`  is a special macro that does not just input a  , similar `~` (the unbreakable space).

What you want to use is `\space`, a literal  :

```
\coordinate (\a\space 1);
```

---

As a work-around, any non-letter character ends the control sequence as well, so

```
\coordinate (\a-1); % or (\a -1)
```

will make the coordinate be named `a-1` which might be easier to deal with than with `\space`s and  s.

You could also use `\def\a#1{a #1}` but don't, that's just very inelegant, in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and the explanation!