# TikZ math library syntax problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, syntax

I am using TikZ math library which is great.

However, I can't get my head around this (see MWE).

I missed something from the documentation (https://tikz.dev/library-math)?

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzmath{ 
\a = 2;
\b = 1;
}
\draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (3,2); % just for orientation    

\draw (\a, \b) circle (2pt);               % no problem here, so \a and \b are fine

\draw [->] (2, 0) arc (0:360:2 and 1);     % no problem here
%\draw [->] (2, 0) arc (0:360:\a and \b);  % gives me an error after removing comment - why?

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\draw [->] (2, 0) arc (0:360:{\a} and {\b});`. Sometimes, the Ti*k*Z parser has a hard time understanding what you tell it when you put macros where it expects letters or numbers. In such cases, it is often a good idea to wrap the macro in curly braces.

Comment: By the way: it is recommended to use a newer syntax for `arc`, which would be `arc[start angle=0, end angle=360, x radius={\a}, y radius={\b}]` (the curly braces would be optional in this case).

Comment: Try `\draw [->] (2, 0) arc (0:360:\a{} and \b);`...

Comment: Or try `\draw [->] (2, 0) arc (0:360:\a\space and \b);`...

Comment: A little bit related because of spaces but with node names: [Q95521](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95521), [Q667361](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/667361). However, with node names `{\a} and {\b}`  would lead to the node name `{2} and {1}` and not `2 and 1`. TikZ expects `<y> and <x>` including the spaced around `and` but the space after `\a` vanishes because it ends the control sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probaby did not miss anything from the manual, but you should note that the Ti*k*Z parser needs to understand a lot of different syntax uses and it is therefore often necessary to help it by wrapping macros or on-the-fly calculations in curly braces. In this case, the space after the macro `\a` is gobbled (so strictly speaking, it is not a parser problem, but wrapping macros in curly braces would still help here):

In this case, the following will solve the problem:

```
\draw [->] (2, 0) arc (0:360:{\a} and {\b});
```

However, note that there is a newer syntax for the `arc` fuction which also would allow you to omit the curly braces. The above would be written as:

```
\draw [->] (2, 0) arc[start angle=0, end angle=360, x radius=\a, y radius=\b];
```

Comment: Not a TikZ parser problem. Just a (La)TeX macro that eats the next space... :-)

Comment: Oh, right! Thanks! Well, the strategy to wrap macros in curly braces in Ti*k*Z is still a good idea ... as it also prevents spaces being gobbled or interpreting unrelated things as part of macro names.